# ESP-IDF project with multiple source files

Tags: cmake, esp32, esp-idf

I started my project with a simple "blink" example and used it as a template to write my code.
This example used only one source file `blink.c`.
Eventually, I want to a use multi source files project and can't figure out how to configure `CMakeLists.txt` in order to compile the project.

My `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)

project(blink)
```

I want to add for example `init.c`.
I tried different ways, but with no success.

None of **idf_component_register() / register_component()** worked for me.

Any idea how to correctly configure the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, the CMake project hierarchy in ESP IDF is a bit tricky. You are looking at the wrong `CMakeLists.txt` file. Instead of the one in root directory, open the one in `blink/main/CMakeLists.txt`. This file lists the source files for the "main" component, which is the one you want to use. It would look like this:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "blink.c" "init.c"
                    INCLUDE_DIRS ".")
```

Make sure your `init.c` file is in the same directory as this `CMakeLists.txt` and `blink.c`.

I also recommend taking a look at the Espressif [Build System documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html), it's quite useful.

Comment: Thank you! It worked.
It was looking for me a little strange, now all the pieces set on their places.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the CMakeLists.txt located in your `main` folder inside your project folder. In addition, you need to put the directory that contains the header files into `INCLUDE_DIRS` parameter.

For example, if you have this file structure in your project (you're putting `init.h` inside `include` folder) as shown below:

```
blink/
├── main/
│   ├── include/
│   │   └── init.h
│   ├── blink.c
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── init.c
│   └── ...
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── ...
```

The content in your `main/CMakeLists.txt` should be:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "blink.c" "init.c"
                    INCLUDE_DIRS "." "include")
```